# Rshiny Datatable does not display all records

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

Is there a limit on the number of rows for R shiny data table? I use Fileinput widget to upload a csv file with 90000 records and 70 columns, then use renderDatatable function to show it to user.

However, my app only shows ~1700 records? Is there anyway to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This displays everything as it should:

```
library(shiny)

testData <- data.frame(replicate(70, sample(0:10, 90000, rep=TRUE)))
write.csv(testData, file = "testData.csv", row.names = FALSE)
csvData <- read.csv("testData.csv")

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable(csvData , options = list(pageLength = 10, width="100%", scrollX = TRUE))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: My code doesnt have the option arguments. Adding them seems to fix the issue.